when using CQRS pattern, business logic ownership problem between query service and command service
We're building query service which is acting as query-side from CQRS pattern. We're aggregating data from multiple team's sources, like product, review, comment and etc. (think it as of normal commerce service).

The problem is that the some specific business logic exists in each team. For example, in review team, when they calculate average rating score, they want to put logics like 1)exclude abuser's review and 2)boost user's review who're living nearby.
I think possible solution would be

review team publish events with average rating score. cons) review team needed to put some kind of worker service to do that.
review team owns and manages query service's review event handler. cons) review team cannot deploy their logic change without query team's approval.

Any other better solution for this? or and tips? thanks in advance!

I think Event Model is best suite for this

@prsutar would you elaborate a little bit more?
